# creating T-SQL form with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am super newbie with Visual Studio.  I want to create an application form in Visual Studio to insert data into my T-SQL database.

I have created a very simple Windows Application Form.  It takes data from fields and insert them into my database. it simple and it works.

Now, what i want to do is to add the function for the app to look if values already exists in the database, so it wont create duplicates.

What im looking for to be checked is first_name, last_name and dob.

as im super newbie, i added an if statement to the Submit button (on click) like below:

```
 private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UserInterface", sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (txtFirstName == sqlCmd.CommandText("EXISTS first_name FROM employee"))
            MessageBox.Show("already exists");
        }
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UserInterface", sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", txtFirstName.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", txtLastName.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept_id", txtDepartmentID.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_title", txtJobTitle.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dateDOB.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start_date", dateStartDate.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contract_type", txtContractType.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status_code", txtStatusCode.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@effect_date", dateEffectDate.Text);             
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Insertion Successful");
            Clear();
        }
    }
    void Clear()
    {
        txtFirstName.Text = txtLastName.Text = txtJobTitle.Text = txtDepartmentID.Text = txtContractType.Text = txtStatusCode.Text = "";
        dateDOB.Text = dateEffectDate.Text = dateStartDate.Text = "";
    }
```

obviously I'm very new and it does not work.

How can i go ahead and do this?

Comment: Post the full code for your connection in C# so it's easier to supply a response. CommandText is a property, not a method (you need to assign the text to it, not supply parameters). In your image the visual studio is underlying it giving you a hint of a problem.

Comment: edited the question ^^

Comment: The compiler must have complained about that `if (txtFirstName == ...` line as there are multiple issues with it. Try and understand what the compiler said. And those messages are a better problem description than "does not work", so please add them to your question. Plus add what you are trying to do

Comment: error says "Error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'SqlCommand.CommandText' cannot be used like a method."

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 3):

A few things to mention on this portion:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UserInterface", sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (txtFirstName == sqlCmd.CommandText("EXISTS first_name FROM employee"))
        MessageBox.Show("already exists");
    }
```

- A `SqlCommand` object can have several command types, 2 of which are `CommandType.StoredProcedure` (which you used to insert your new records) and `CommandType.Text` which is used to supply plain SQL directly. For this case you want to set it as plain text so change that line to:

  ```
  sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  ```
- The first parameter of the constructor of the `SqlCommand` is the command text. If the command is gonna be a stored procedure call, then you need to pass the SP name (which you've done when inserting your new row), but if you want plain SQL then you can write it here (I modified the SQL to actually search for the first name in a safe way, preventing **SQL Injection**):

  ```
  SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT first_name FROM employee WHERE first_name = @firstName", sqlCon);
  DbParameter firstNameParameter = new SqlParameter("@firstName", txtFirstName.Text.Trim());
  sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(firstNameParameter);
  ```
- You need to execute the command with the `ExecuteReader()` method, and this will return a reader object you need to use to retrieve it's results (the SQL might return several rows).

  ```
  using (DbDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
  while (reader.Read())
  {
      MessageBox.Show("already exists");
      break;
  }
  ```

This is a head-start so you can keep on coding, many things to improve yet but might be too much if explained all of a sudden.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT first_name FROM employee WHERE first_name = @firstName", sqlCon);
    DbParameter firstNameParameter = new SqlParameter("@firstName", txtFirstName.Text.Trim());
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(firstNameParameter);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    sqlCon.Open();

    using (DbDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("already exists");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: EzLo, many thanks dude, however it now has the error "The type or namespace name 'DbParameter' could not be found" and "The type or namespace name 'DbDataReader could not be found". am i missing something?

Comment: Add the proper reference on the upper part of the CS file: `using System.Data.SqlClient`. If on visual studio, hover the mouse over the underlined part and it will suggest to add the proper reference automatically whenever it's missing.

Comment: many thanks mate. in the meantime, i changed my database in sql a bit as well, so i created a 'helper' column which concatenates first_name, last_name and dob into one single entity, and added a constraint so it can be unique. now, if i try to execute the application i made without all the above codes, if i try to insert any dupes it would return an internal error. how i go about this being shown as error on its own, meaning if it was a standalone exe file?

Comment: You need to catch the exception from SQL Server then and display the error message to the user. Use a try/catch in C# and read about exceptions, they are crucial to object oriented programming.

Comment: @P.MAJ I'm glad to help, please mark this as answer so the question gets marked as answered if it helped.